# Hibernate, spring and thymeleaf : exception handling

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm working on a spring mvc web application lately using thymeleaf as view engine, hibernate as persistence unit and spring security. I opted for an XML-less approch (using javaConfig)

I want to provide some customized error pages and not only one global page for all the errors.

I'm new to hibernate and such, so my question is , what are the exceptions that i should handel, for example when the application can't reach the database or something like that, what kind of exceptions does hibernate throw, and for thymeleaf too, how can catch the exceptions it throws ?

One more thing, can i handle the 404 errors : for example, if the user enter an inexisting url, i want to redirect him to an error page, or to the home page, how should i proceed using java config ?

Answer (score 1):

Without more specifics, the standard and generic response for providing custom error handling and error pages in Spring MVC is documented in the following section within the Spring Reference:  [17.11 Handling exceptions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers).  This section is sufficient to answer all the error page/handling questions you've mentioned.

For Hibernate, the it should throw an `org.hibernate.HibernateException` or subtype of it.  Handling `org.hibernate.HibernateException` should be sufficient for UI purposes.  For a list of exceptions, the `org.hibernate.HibernateException` API docs for your Hibernate version will have a list of all known subtypes.  For example:  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/HibernateException.html